# Store image in h2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, h2

I am working with Spring MVC architecture and Hibernate using H2 Database.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add New Product</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Add New Product !!</p>
<form:form action="addProducttoDB" commandName="product" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Product id :<br>
<label>Product Name : </label><form:input  path="product_name" value="Product Name"/> <br>
Product Desc : <form:input path="product_desc" value="Product Desc"/><br>
Select Image :<form:input type="file" path=""/><br> 
Submit : <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

As in above code - its storing the information about prodouct and adding to Database using action request -> "addProducttoDB" , Model object -> product

And path is the column name, now I would like to save an image along with the details. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following change

- give name to `<form:input type="file" path="productImg" name="productImg/>`
- Declare MultipartFile object in method signature where datastore logic is there
- call the save saveMultipartFile method inside the save method

### method

```
private void saveMultipartFile( MultipartFile files)
{
    if(!files.isEmpty()){
        try {
            String fileName = files.getOriginalFilename();
            String dirLocation ="Path where you want to save image";
            if(!new File(dirLocation).exists()){
                File file = new File(dirLocation);
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            byte[] bytes = files.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dirLocation+new File(fileName)));
            bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```